# Is there any way to get Visual Studio to remember the last caret position?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor, lost-focus

So there I am coding away in the VS editor. Then focus gets needlessly stolen by some other part of the (bloated) GUI and I lose track of where I was - the text caret just disappears.

Is there any way of either stopping the focus being stolen or, failing that, of getting VS to remember the last caret position?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure exactly what you mean, but if you use the mouse to click into the code-editor, then the cursor will automatically go to the position (or nearest possible) of the *(edit) mouse click*.  If you use the `Window` menu and then choose the file again (i.e. don't use the mouse) is the cursor where you expect?  A shortcut would be `Alt-W-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the shortcuts to go back and forth through caret history are:

Back: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Forward: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

(<kbd>-</kbd> is a dash)

Comment: @freefaller how do you annotate the keys like that?

Comment: It's the very useful `<kbd>keyname</kbd>` tags. You can check any formatting by clicking the "edit" link on the post :-)